# Setting new Azure Pipelines Agent - locks admin accounts out

Tags: azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I need some expert help ;) I have a new Windows 10 system configured with domain users + some others (all worked fine).

My next step was to set up that box as an Azure DevOps Self-hosted agent. I have followed these instructions - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/windows-agent?view=azure-devops

What has happened (x2 already), and I can not figure it out, is once I restarted the agent **ALL my admin user accounts are no longer admin. Not even I, as a domain admin, can undo these changes.**

[image]

e.g case. When I want to remove it from agents. I get this error.

```
[2023-05-31 14:27:52Z INFO Terminal] WRITE LINE: Removing autologon settings
[2023-05-31 14:27:52Z ERR  AutoLogonManager] Needs Administrator privileges to unconfigure an agent running with AutoLogon capability.
[2023-05-31 14:27:52Z INFO Terminal] WRITE LINE: Failed: Removing autologon settings
[2023-05-31 14:27:52Z ERR  Agent]     Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.WebApi.SecurityException: Needs Administrator privileges to unconfigure an agent running with autologon capability.
```

Does anyone know what is going on and how I can fix it without reinstalling the OS?